# android-How to use CursorAdapter to fill listView and recycling them

Tags: android, sqlite, android-listview, android-sqlite, android-cursoradapter

I used to fill listView with arrayAdapter and recycle them to do faster and reduce ram usage . 
I want to do the same with CursorAdapter ,I mean I want to read data( lots of data , about 500 rows ) with images and show them . 
What is the best way to do this ? What should I do and where I can learn what to do . 
I've searched but I'm really confuse now ,I'm a new to android.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an Example with comments to show you how to recycle the views in `CursorAdapter` that has 2 textViews as an Item in the List.

here is the class `ViewHolder` to hold the elements and call them once.

```
public class ViewHolder {

    TextView tvTitle, tvGenre;
    public ViewHolder(View row)
    {
        tvTitle = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.tvTitle);
        tvGenre = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.tvGenre);
    }


}
```

in your `newView`

```
@Override
public View newView(Context context, Cursor arg1, ViewGroup arg2) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, arg2, false);

    //create an instance of the holder
    ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder(row);
    //add it to the Tag, so if it not null get the elements from tag.   
    row.setTag(holder);

    return row;
}
```

in your `bindView`

```
Override
public void bindView(View v, Context context, Cursor c) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    //create an instance of the class and assign its value from view tag
    ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();

    //use the holder to assign values to the elements   
    holder.tvTitle.setText(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHolder.TITLE_KEY)));
    holder.tvGenre.setText(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHolder.GENRE_KEY)));

}
```

Hope this example is clear to you, change it according to your Item.

**...**

update: Based on demanding `DatabaseHolder` class

public class DatabaseHolder {

```
private final static String DATABASE_NAME = "MoviesDatabase";
private final static String TABLE_NAME = "MoviesTable";
private final static int VERSION = 1;

public final static String ID_KEY = "_id";
public final static String TITLE_KEY = "title";
public final static String GENRE_KEY = "genre";
public final static String DESC_KEY = "description";

public final static String[] COLUMNS = {ID_KEY, TITLE_KEY, GENRE_KEY, DESC_KEY};

private Context  context;
private SQLiteDatabase myDB;
private OpenHelper helper;

public DatabaseHolder(Context context)
{
    this.context = context;
}

public class OpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    Context context;

    public OpenHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, TABLE_NAME, null, VERSION);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        try {
            db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE "+ TABLE_NAME +" ( " +
                    ID_KEY + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                    TITLE_KEY + " TEXT(32) NOT NULL, " +
                    GENRE_KEY + " TEXT(32) NOT NULL, " +
                    DESC_KEY + " TEXT(512) NOT NULL);"
                    );
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            Message.message(context, "Failed"+e);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
        onCreate(db);
    }


}

public DatabaseHolder open()
{
    helper = new OpenHelper(context);
    myDB = helper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;
}

public long insertMovie(String title, String genre, String desc) {

    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();

    cv.put(TITLE_KEY, title);
    cv.put(GENRE_KEY, genre);
    cv.put(DESC_KEY, desc);

    return myDB.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, cv);

}

public Cursor getAllRowCursor() {

    Cursor c = myDB.query(TABLE_NAME, COLUMNS, null, null, null, null, null);

    if (c != null)
        c.moveToFirst();

    return c;
}

public Cursor getSpecificRows(int id) {

    String where = ID_KEY + " = " + id;
    Cursor c = myDB.query(TABLE_NAME, COLUMNS, where, null, null, null, null);

    if (c != null)
        c.moveToFirst();

    return c;

}

public Cursor getFilteredRows(String result)
{
    result = "'" + result.trim() + "%'";
    String where = TITLE_KEY + " LIKE " + result;
    Cursor c = myDB.query(TABLE_NAME, COLUMNS, where, null, null, null, null);

    if (c != null)
        c.moveToFirst();

    return c;


}

public void truncate() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    myDB.delete(TABLE_NAME, null, null);
}
}
```

Comment: thanks you , could you give me an example what is behind this part of code , DatabaseHolder.TITLE_KEY  and the whole curseradapter code ? I couldn't use it

Comment: The DatabaseHolder is my database class where I have my columns like TITLE and GENRE... You just have to use the ViewHolder and assign the tag of the row to the holder then use the holder to assign values to your element

Comment: I've been working on it for 7 hours ,Still nothing . Could you please post your DatabaseHelper either ?

Comment: I have added the database class, hope you find it useful